# Flutter Hover On Button Changes Text Letter Spacing

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web

Can someone please tell me why is this happening? When I hover over a button, the text letter spacing above changes. Both button are the same but somehow it's only happening to one button?

Flutter Button Hover Bug

[image]

```
                             Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  FittedBox(
                                    fit: BoxFit.contain,
                                    child: FlatButton(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                          horizontal: 40.0, vertical: 15.0),
                                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                        borderRadius:
                                            BorderRadius.circular(80.0),
                                        side: BorderSide(
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                          width: 3,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context)
                                          .pushNamed(EnterView.routeName),
                                      child: Text(
                                        'YES',
                                        style: Styles.boldBodyText(),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(width: 30.0),
                                  FittedBox(
                                    fit: BoxFit.contain,
                                    child: FlatButton(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                          horizontal: 40.0, vertical: 15.0),
                                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                        borderRadius:
                                            BorderRadius.circular(80.0),
                                        side: BorderSide(
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                          width: 3,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      onPressed: _toNotQueue,
                                      child: Text(
                                        'NO',
                                        style: Styles.boldBodyText(),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              )
```

Comment: did you fix it? @Ray-C

Comment: @Nauzet No I did not and moved on. But I haven't tried it on the latest updates.

Comment: Failed to reproduce the issue on FlutterV3, consider upgrading flutter and provide full scaffold that will reproduce the issue